# How to keep all instances in AWS Auto-scaling Group updated after deploying new code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, deployment, capistrano, autoscaling

I am trying to build a more dynamic/scalable system in **AWS**. I have launched **2 instances** in an **AutoScaling group** where **the minimum number of instances** is **2** and **the maximum** is **5** with a **load balancer** in front of them. I have **enabled "Termination Protection"** on the first two instances since they are going to be the ones that I use for **deploying** my **Rails Application via Capistrano**.

The problem is that I am not sure what is the best way to keep all instances in my autoscaling group up-to-date so they run the same version of the application.

I have searched for many techniques, below are the ones I find applicable but still do not know which would be the best.

**1- AWS CodeDeploy:** Looks pretty cool, using **Blue/Green Deployment** looks like it would do the job pretty solid with zero downtime. I do not know if there's a rule of thumb for this but in my opinion, the **deployment time is a bit long**, I am **not sure** if it would be **applicable when I need to release a hotfix**.

**2- Via Script:** I am not sure how to implement this using AWS either but, the idea is when a new code is uploaded to my 2 "master (?)" instances,

1. I will **create** a **new Launch Configuration** using the **new AMI**
2. **Update the autoscaling group** to use that new launch configuration
3. **Scale down** my autoscaling group to **terminate the instances** that are **running the old configuration**
4. Hopefully, autoscaling policies will **create new instances** using the **new launch configuration**

The problem with this approach is that it **requires some manual operation** which I do not want to rely on much.

**3- Using User Data:** Running new instances with user data that pulls the new version of the code. I do not think this is a good way since probably there will be other instances that are already running the old code.

So these are the solutions I have seen up to now, which one would be the best solution?

Cheers!

Comment: Have you considered Elastic Beanstalk? Everything including deployment, auto scaling, load balancing, etc. is managed for you.

Comment: Thanks, John. Actually, I did but the deployment takes a bit longer, right? Would that be a problem?

Comment: Also, I want to have more control over the system I use. I am not an expert as you can clearly tell so I also do not have the experience to separate "RDS" to increase deployment speed, etc.

Comment: @recepinanc - It is really helped me thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I ended up using an extension gem (my app is written in ruby on rails) for deployment. I was already using `Capistrano` for deployment, then I found out the gem [`elbas`](https://github.com/lserman/capistrano-elbas) which internally does the following:

- Deploy your code to each running instance connected to a given AutoScale group
- After deployment, create an AMI from one of the running instances
- Attach the AMI with the new code to a new AWS Launch Configuration
- Update your AutoScale group to use the new launch configuration
- Delete any old AMIs created by ELBAS
- Delete any old launch configurations created by ELBAS

This is basically the 2nd option (via Script option), and finding a gem that does this for me, removes the challenge of manually handling things.

Hope this helps, cheers!